Why is my graph wrong when trying to visualize the max-cut in qiskit?
I think my QAOA code is correctly solving the max-cut but the visualization is wrong.
I am working on solving the Max-cut problem using QAOA. I started small-scale with a 5 node bipartite graph. I extracted from the counts the most frequent bitstring and the max-cut value and they're both correct. When trying to visualize the graph, the nodes are not being colored correctly, they are being colored in a way that doesn't represent the max cut. I am trying to understand what is wrong, either my visualization function, the qubit-to-node mapping, or something else in my code. I would like some insight on what the issue might be.
Attached is my output and below is a code snippet to visualize the results:
## Visualize the final results
colors = ["r" if bit == "0" else "b" for bit in max(counts, key=counts.get)]
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(G, [0,1,2])
plt.figure()
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=colors, with_labels=True)
plt.show() 



This could happen if the nodes in the graph were added "out-of-order", i.e.:
  G = nx.Graph()
  G.add_node(0)
  G.add_node(3) # <<< notice adding nodes 3 and 4 before adding 1 and 2
  G.add_node(4)
  G.add_node(1)
  G.add_node(2)
  G.add_edges_from([
      (0, 3),
      (0, 4),
      (1, 3),
      (1, 4),
      (2, 3),
      (2, 4),
  ])

The solution is to re-order your list colors according to the order of nodes in the graph, i.e.:
colors = [colors[i] for i in list(G.nodes())]

Here's my full notebook that replicates your issue:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LDDWr9lH9G2Lh5Z1VqTFK7RsVl35WLHi?usp=sharing

